# Need help multiplying positive numbers in a list by 3, and leaving other numbers unmodified

Tags: python, list, numbers, multiplication

My goal is to multiply all positive numbers in a list by 3. I think I've almost got the solution but I'm not sure what is causing it not to work. It currently just returns back the original numbers and does not multiply any numbers by 3.

```
def triple_positives(xs):
    List = []
    product = 3
    for i in range (len(List)):
        if List[i] >= 0:
            product *= i
        List.append(xs[i])
    return xs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, there are multiple issues. Below is the updated version of it with fixes:

```
>>> def triple_positives(xs):
...     List = []
...     product = 3
...     for i in range (len(xs)):
...         if xs[i] >= 0:
...             List.append(xs[i]*3)
...         else:
...             List.append(xs[i])
...     return List
...
>>> my_list = [1, 2, -1, 5, -2]
>>> triple_positives(my_list)
[3, 6, -1, 15, -2]
```

Alternatively, you may achieve this using List Comprehension as:

```
>>> [item * 3 if item > 0 else item for item in my_list]
[3, 6, -1, 15, -2]
```

Comment: Thank you it is still not working for some reason but your solution has helped me figure out what I need to do

Comment: It should be working. I have copied the working code from my console. Check whether you copied and pasted everything I mentioned.

Comment: @user75747475 If there's something wrong with it and you already know what, then why not say what, so it can be fixed here as well?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm not exactly sure what is wrong the code works but it just returns the same numbers. For example it says "triple_positives([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]) incorrectly updated to [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]"

Comment: Are you sure that your code is returning `List` and not `xs`?

Comment: @user75747475 Were you actually told it incorrectly "updated"? Maybe you're not supposed to return anything at all, but instead modify the given list object?

Comment: Actually I'm now certain that's it, since two *"other"* people asked the same question with the same nonsense code ([here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:a8U3pfFzTeYJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/39840116/given-list-of-numbers-any-positive-numbers-are-tripled-and-others-0s-and-n+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840724/given-a-list-of-numbers-any-positive-numbers-are-tripled)) and the latter made it clear to return `None`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Nice catch! I am not sure how all the three have same code which is in-fact incorrect. May be they should change there tutor.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri You actually think they're different people? I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over an empty list, and that loop would be trying to access elements that don't exist, change the `product`, and append unchanged elements from the original list to the new list. And then you return the original, unchanged list anyway. Basically, almost every line in your code is wrong.

You should be looping over the input list and appending multiplied elements to the new list, then return the new list:

```
def triple_positives(xs):
    List = []
    product = 3
    for i in xs:
        if i > 0:
            List.append(i*product)
    return List
```

Also, 0 is not a positive number. Use `>` instead of `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your function it should be something like this.
0 is not a positive number.So using > instead of >=.

```
def triple_positives(xs):
    List = []
    product = 3
    for i in xs:
        if i > 0:
            i=i*product
        List.append(i)
    return List
```

But this can be done like this also

```
def triple_positives(xs):
    return [3*i if i>0 else i for i in xs  ]
```

Comment: Shorter list comp just for fun: `[2*x+abs(x) for x in xs]`

Comment: *"0 is not a positive number"* - but whether you count it as positive, negative or neither, `0 * 3 == 0`!